# Jenkins: File Operations Plugin

Tags: jenkins

I just started with using jenkins, and learning a lot.
Installed on windows 7.
One thing i can figure out is about File operations plugin.

I don't know how to set up just simple "copy, paste" from one location to another.

Yea maybe is dumb, but i just cant figure out, try a lot of and always got build break.

What i need to set up for simple test ? like i liked to say, show me a door, i'll figure out rest :)

[image: what to write herE?]

Answer (score 0):

The include file pattern wants an ANT style filter (relative to your workspace as the root).

Include File Pattern:  `myWorkspaceSubFolder\*.txt`

Target location also assumes the root workspace though I guess you can redirect it to another drive.

Comment: myWorkspaceSubFolder\\*.txt (my \ got stripped out above)

Comment: Do you have any example lets say:   

I wanna do backup from \\backup1\folder1 to--> \\backup2\c:\, \\backup3\c:\, \\backup4\c:\  and lets say some sort of distrubtions...
 
Then i wanna package that (zip, rar whatever) that folders on the \\backup4\backup


I didnt find any kind of commands for this plugin.

Thanks ahaid!